# Jquery iterate over an array of Objects

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops

hello I want to iterate an array of objects and render them in a table. 
I'm pretty new to this so im struggling to iterate over each inner object.
Any help appreciated.
Here is my array of objects:
I can get a length of the whole array but not the length of each object(final Product).
Would I iterate over the whole array and then another loop for each object inside? How do i get the length of this object inside the array and should i use a for loop or for each loop?
many thanks.

```
var output = [finalProduct { DeviceName="gkorosi-lt2",  Product="Photoshop CC",  Status="Active"},
          finalProduct { DeviceName="gkorosi-lt3",  Product="Illustrator CC",  Status="Active"}];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you whant to use JQuery, you can use `$.each` function

```js
var output = [{
    finalProduct: {
      DeviceName: "gkorosi-lt2",
      Product: "Photoshop CC",
      Status: "Active"
    }
  },
  {
    finalProduct: {
      DeviceName: "gkorosi-lt3",
      Product: "Illustrator CC",
      Status: "Active"
    }
  }
];

$.each(output, function(key, value) {
  $("body").append("<div>" + value.finalProduct.DeviceName + "</div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I had to keep my original data structure and using these *For loops*, I managed to get it to work.

```
for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++){
  $(".trbody").append("<td>"+ output[i].DeviceName.toUpperCase() + "</td>");
    //etc
}
```